# Is it possible to add hyperlink in TODO IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea.
Is it possible to add hyperlink in TODO without using Javadocs?

Example:

```
    //todo maybe we have to delete this method, 
    //have another method now {someMethodByDTO} <-link to method
    public Object someMethod(){
     // method body
    }
```

Comment: It is method documentation, not TODO!!!

Comment: This is an examle. Question is about link in todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add link to method in the comment.
You can only create a clickable comment to refer some url.

**Clickable comments**

> If a documentation comment contains a hyperlink, you can make it
>   clickable.
>
> To do that, do one of the following:
>
> Keep the Ctrl key pressed and hover your mouse pointer over the
>   hyperlink. Press Ctrl+B.

See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-documentation-comments.html)

Answer (score 0):

For using a hyperlink for ex. a website, you can use:

```
/*
 * https://www.google.co.uk/
 */
```

You can click it with ctrl-click.
If you want to use something like:

```
// {@link YourMethod}
```

That is not possible.

**BUT** If you have a method which is not used anymore, but don't want to delete it, why don't you use `@Deprecated` and add some comments too, if you want.

Comment: It was an example about delete